# Why my dynamic routing returns a blank page?

Tags: reactjs, firebase, react-router-dom

So I am relatively new to the dynamic routing in React.js.
I have encountered one problem, which I cannot solve for about the last 2 hours.
I have a simple webpage with the blog posts on it and I wanted to create a 'Read More' route, which would redirect to the full article page.

So far, after clicking on these link, it redirects to the correct link, however, it does not display anything.
I have tried many things but I cannot see where the problem could be.

Could anyone take a look at this project and let me know why there is nothing being rendered? I believe it might be the problem with the improper importing but I cannot see where.

Please, see the GitHub repo of this project. There are App.js, Post.js, Postlink.js and Post.js that I wanted to connect with each other.

The Postlink.js is the page where I wanted to render full content of my post but it is not being rendered by React.

https://github.com/szygendaborys/LiderAPP

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two problems:

1) Your Route match is wrong (you've written `post/:id` when it should be `posts/:id`):

```
export const POSTLINK = '/posts/:id'
```

2) In your `Postlink` `componentDidMount()`, you've need to call `firebase.posts` as a function

```
 const ref = this.props.firebase.posts().doc(this.props.match.params.id)
```

(in your repo it is `this.props.firebase.posts.doc`)

Comment: 1) Oh great, such a dumb mistake :D Thank you!

2) Thanks for pointing this out, I believe it is not my day today :D

Answer (score 1):

It seems you've made a mistake with "export const POSTLINK = '/post/:id';"
Because when I click more, I go to '/post**s**/:id'; (watch the s). But when I try to change it, I get multiple firebase errors, which I have no knowledge about.

At least changing your route to:

```
"export const POSTLINK = '/posts/:id';"
```

Loads the right component.

Hope this helps.